# How to run double JVM on one computer

Tags: java, jvm

It's possible to run double JVM on one computer? Then how to do?

Comment: please clarify the term 'double JVM'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running multiple JVMs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030255/running-multiple-jvms)

Comment: I mean multiple JVM. Thank you Pascal.

Comment: If one JVM is good, two must be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

A JVM is simply a process.  You just start the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

Running two JVM? Just run the `java` twice, starting the same or different applications. What exactly you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example:

```
$ java -jar SwingSet2/SwingSet2.jar ; java -jar Java2D/Java2D.jar
```

Addendum: Here are two more complex examples: a [command line program](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/99ce4ce118ea2293) to start/stop a GUI program in a separate JVM; a [Swing program](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/c81f8c5f269e22e5) to start/stop a different Swing program in a separate JVM.

Answer (score 3):

If what you're looking for is being able to run two different versions of the JVM, say you have an app that's been tested with a given version, say 1.4.y,  but you want to experiment with a newer version, say 1.6.21, you need to set your
**JAVA_HOME** environment variable. This tells your system where to look for java.

In linux/bash it's as easy as adding the following to your bashrc, or the shell script that runs your app:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/toplevel-jvm-dir
```

Here's a link for windows [Setting JAVA_HOME via GUIs](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7850/inst_jdk_javahome_t?l=en&a=view) and 
batch:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07
```

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to **JVM IMPLEMENTATION** : Yes you can have multiple installations in your machine. Just install multiple JREs.

OR

Referring to **JVM RUNTIME INSTANCE** : Each application gets its own JVM instance. So just run 2 applications and you will get 2 JVM instances.

Eg : deploy two war files in tomcat. In this case there are 2 JVM instances in a single JRE.