# How two applications running on two different JVM will interact each other?

Tags: java, jvm

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [inter jvm communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810212/inter-jvm-communication)
>   [Communication between two separate Java desktop applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680898/communication-between-two-separate-java-desktop-applications)
>   [Running multiple JVMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030255/running-multiple-jvms)

How two applications running on two different JVM will interact each other ? If possible please provide some examples ?

Comment: Global variabls probably

Comment: Can you please be more specific

Comment: Distributed Cache?  EhCache and Terracotta?

Comment: Thanks Guys for the posts. It is clear from NAVEEDs post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reuben, you can use Web services or JMS

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/